# How to select all the linkbutton in Asp.net using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 15 link buttons on my Page,I have to write a common function for each link button,How do i select All Link buttons using Jquery

I have tried this,

```
function Myfunction() {

        $('input[type=text]').mouseenter(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: "TreeDemo.aspx/dataCode",
                  data: "{'Code':'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data) {
                     $('#<%=tbDetails.ClientID %>').empty();
                     for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                         $('#<%=tbDetails.ClientID %>').append("<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Address + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>phone:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Phone + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Email:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Email + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Branch:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].branch + "</td></tr>");


                     }
                     $('#<%=panel.ClientID %>').dialog("open");

                 },
                 error: function(result) {
                     alert("Error");
                 }
             });

         });
```

But its only working for textboxes not for link button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LinkButton is rendered as an anchor tag, so you can simply select all link buttons like this:-

```
$('a').mouseenter(function()
```

If you have some extra attribute on your linkbutton say CssClass:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkTest" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Page.aspx"
 Text="Hello" CssClass="clsTest"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then you can filter your linkbuttons like this:-

```
$('a[class="clsTest"]').mouseenter(function()
```

If you need to select both, textbox as well as LinkButton then:-

```
$('input[type="text"],a[class="clsTest"]').mouseenter(function()
```

Comment: But its for both text box and link button, i need only for link button ,how  do i change that

Comment: Which one?   if i removed the text box its not working

Comment: data: "{'Code':'" + $(this).val() + "'}" In this line Post data is  nothing only empty values @Rahul Singh

Comment: @King_Fisher - Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: Whats diff of val() and text() ?

Comment: @King_Fisher - It all depends on controls, few controls gives text with `text` property some gives with `val`